# Java screen sharing program

Tags: java, windows, tcp, client-server

I want to create a multi-cllient client-server program in which the server has separate windows to display all clients screens, to monitor what's going on on their computers. How will i do it?

i want to know how will i display the screen on the server i am using a GUI interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll set out your requirements, come up with an initial design, flesh out the design, begin implementing it, and then refine the design, continue implementing, test, and debug until you have a satisfactory implementation. If you run into trouble or have specific questions, you can ask more questions.

Comment: I wanted to know how will i begin i.e ho to send the video screens from the client side, as i am new, i don't have any idea about this. I do know the sockets, and reading and writing to it but only for strings. i want to know how will i proceed for doing this and what all i need to know

Comment: previously i had made the chat program

Comment: As I said, start out by setting out your requirements. Then you can start to come up with an initial design. (I wasn't joking. I'm honestly trying to help you. What are the bandwidth requirements? Resolution requirements? Latency requirements? All those things will drive the design. This is a serious project and this is how serious projects are done. Don't forget to document the client/server protocol.)

Comment: I am a noob you may say then, I just wanted to practice java by building such thing. Thus i have no plan or something. basically i would be running the client and server on same  machine only, so bandwidth is not an issue. also the design is just basic as i am interested in the logic of the program as of now. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: If you have no requirements, then just do whatever you want. I guess I don't know what your question is then.